# can't run php in xampp

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

In my Xampp htdocs file I have placed the html code below, and a php file, test.php, whose contents are also given below. When I click the button I get no error messages and, alas, no indication that the php program has run. Any suggestions ?

I should also add that, using the: form action = "http://localhost/test.php"  construct, the test.php does actually execute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc() {

   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "xxx";
     } ;
}
       xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/test.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>

The test.php module is just:
<?php
echo "Hello there"
?>
```

Comment: You are doing a AJAX request. Press F12 (chrome/firefox), go to network tab and see if a request was made.

Comment: It works for me when I reproduce it on my machine... Don't you see the `xxx` text appear once you click?